# Need help making it so that balls can only be dropped from the top part of the game

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

[playing game from anywhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqQuz.png)

Hi, so I want the user to only be able to click from above the top row of pegs to drop the ball through the pegs. As it stands now you can simply touch anywhere on the screen, including in the goals and the ball will go there. I have tried using an if statement and CGPoint to make it so that you can only drop it from above the pegs, but I am too beginner to figure it out. Thanks.

Here's my code, using Swift 2 and Xcode 7:  I figure that it will go in here...

```
    for touch in touches {

        if self.nunus.count >= numberOfNunus {
            self.removeChildrenInArray(self.nunus)
            self.nunus = []
            self.score = 0
            updateLabels()
        } else {

            let nunu = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"nunu")

            nunu.xScale = 0.13
            nunu.yScale = 0.13
            nunu.position = touch.locationInNode(self)

            nunu.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: nunu.size.height / 2)
            nunu.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = self.nunuCategory
            nunu.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = self.pegCategory | self.borderCategory | self.postCategory | self.nunuCategory
            nunu.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = smallGoalCategory | self.mediumGoalCategory | self.bigGoalCategory



            self.addChild(nunu)

            self.nunus.append(nunu)
            updateLabels()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's bad form to post several hundred lines of code and expect your reader to sort through it all to figure out your issue. Please edit your question to point us to the relevant code and explain what your current logic does.

Comment: And "can anyone help?" is not a question.

Comment: To clarify, it might be a question grammatically, but it doesn't meet the Stack Overflow definition of a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

This codes creates and drop node if only you touch higher than midle of scene. If you whant to change Height change this line:

```
if location.y > worl.frame.size.height / 2
```

For example:

```
if location.y > worl.frame.size.height * 0.8
```

Means your touch position must be higher than 80% your scene height

`touchesBegan` :

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        //let touchedNode = nodeAtPoint(location)

        if location.y > worl.frame.size.height / 2 {

            createNode()
        }
    }
}

func createAndDropNode() {

    //code here
}
```

> world - SKNode of exactly same size as your SKScene

Comment: Thank you for your help. You got me going in the right direction!  I added this:  if touch.locationInNode(self).y > 500

Comment: You shouldn use that line, i recomend doing something like this: if touch.locationInNode(self).y > world.frame.size.height / 18 * 16

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The point on the iPhone screen was at 500 or above. So if the user touched below the 500 point the code to drop the ball would not run.  I added this line of code: **if touch.locationInNode(self).y > 500**

func touchesBegan(touches: Set, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */

```
    for touch in touches {

        if touch.locationInNode(self).y > 500 {


        if self.nunus.count >= numberOfNunus {
            self.removeChildrenInArray(self.nunus)
            self.nunus = []
            self.score = 0
            updateLabels()
        } else {

            let nunu = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"nunu")

            nunu.xScale = 0.13
            nunu.yScale = 0.13
            nunu.position = touch.locationInNode(self)

            nunu.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: nunu.size.height / 2)
            nunu.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = self.nunuCategory
            nunu.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = self.pegCategory | self.borderCategory | self.postCategory | self.nunuCategory
            nunu.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = smallGoalCategory | self.mediumGoalCategory | self.bigGoalCategory




            self.addChild(nunu)

            self.nunus.append(nunu)
            updateLabels()
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: iPhone 5,5s have 568 but other phones have more. http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions

Comment: So then you switch to another device it wont be corect